# passing by reference not working

Tags: c#

I have following code

```
public interface IEntity
{
// Properties
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Container : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Command
{      
    public void ApplyCommand(ref IEntity entity)
    {
        Container c = new Container() { Id = 20 };
        entity = c;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ReferenceTest
{
    [Test] 
    public void Casting_ByRef_Not_ReturningValue()
    {
        Container c= new Container();
        IEntity entity = c;
        new Command().ApplyCommand(ref entity);           
        Assert.AreEqual(c.Id, 20);            
    }
}
```

the test is failing, shouldn't passing by reference allow object reference change ?

Comment: Is it failing the .AreEqual or is it failing with CCE (Class cast exception)?  I know this may sound odd, but try doing some Console.WriteLine to see where things are going amiss.

Comment: Instead of WriteLines, have a look at a TestRunner (www.testdriven.net or rehsarper) which allows you to run the tests from within the IDE while in Debug mode.

Comment: Remember, "ref" does not mean "pass by reference". It means "the parameter of this method is a reference (that is, an alias) to another variable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your test you change the object that `entity` is pointing to, but you're comparing the object `c` is pointing to.

Remember that references are copied on assignment, so that you create a new `Container`, let `c` be a reference to that object. Then you copy that reference by assigning `c` to `entity`. Now both `entity` and `c` refer to the same object. You pass `ref entity` into the method, thereby changing `entity` but not touching `c`.

```
Container c= new Container();
IEntity entity = c;
new Command().ApplyCommand(ref entity);
Assert.AreEqual(entity.Id, 20);
```

should definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

This test is working just fine.  You have 2 references (c and entity) which point to a single object of type `Container`.  When you make the call to ApplyCommand you are only changing the value of the reference entity.  The reference c is unchanged and still points to the original `Container` object.

Here is a way to write the test to show the difference

```
    Container c= new Container();
    IEntity entity = c;
    new Command().ApplyCommand(ref entity);           
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(entity, typeof(Container));
    c = (Container)entity;
    Assert.AreEqual(c.Id, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ref works perfectly, but the reference variable `c` is not involved.

If you run the test `Assert.AreEqual(entity.Id, 20);` it will pass.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 Assert.AreEqual(entity.Id, 20);
```

When you write

```
  IEntity entity = c;
```

you create another reference variable on the stack, with `c`'s address in it. This `entity` variable is what you are passing by ref to the method, not the `c` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing a reference to an object you created in another method and you are pointing your IEntity instance to that object.